# Partial View replaces Parent view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm working on web app developed in ASP.Net MVC, having a partial view which should be rendered inside its parent view.

- Parent view has a HTML Dropdown, on-change event should bind respective data to partial view. But on selection change, the complete parent view is replaced with partial view (child view).

*Parent View (Index.cshtml)*

```
<h3>Please Select Group</h3>    
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeDeptHistory", "Home", FormMethod.Post))    
{    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    if (ViewBag.DepartmentList != null)    
    {    
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentName", ViewBag.DepartmentList as SelectList, "-- Select --", new { Class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })    
    }    
}    
<div>    
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_EmployeeDeptHistory");}    
</div>
```

*Partial View (_EmployeeDeptHistory.cshtml)*

```
@model IEnumerable<PartialViewApplSol.Models.EmployeeDepartmentHistory>    
@if (Model != null)    
{    
    <h3>Employees Department History : @Model.Count()</h3>    

    foreach (var item in Model)    
    {    
        <div style="border:solid 1px #808080; margin-bottom:2%;">    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>Name</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.Name</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>Shift</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.Shift</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>Department</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.Department</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>Group Name</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.GroupName</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>Start Date</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.StartDate</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-2">    
                    <strong>End Date</strong>    
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-5">    
                    <span>@item.EndDate</span>    
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>    
    }    
}
```

I think the possible mistake is returning partial-view on drop down selection changed.

```
[HttpPost]    
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public ActionResult EmployeeDeptHistory(FormCollection form)    
{    
    IEnumerable<EmployeeDepartmentHistory> empHistList;    
    using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))    
    {    
        empHistList = con.Query<EmployeeDepartmentHistory>("sp_StoredProc", new { DeptId = form["DepartmentName"] }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);    
    }    
    return View("_EmployeeDeptHistory", empHistList);    
}
```

Comment: Your method is returning your partial, not the main view! If you are just wanting to update part of the existing page, then use ajax to call the method and update the DOM in its `success` callback

Comment: @StephenMuecke can i only render partial view inside parent view using ajax. Do we have any other work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of standard form submit, you need to use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to load partial view inside HTML element without replacing parent view. Here are those steps:

1) Remove `onchange` event from `DropDownList` helper, and assign AJAX callback bound to `change` event:

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentName", ViewBag.DepartmentList as SelectList, "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**jQuery (inside`$(document).ready()`)**

```
$('#DepartmentName').change(function () {
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();

   if (selectedValue && selectedValue != '')
   {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeDeptHistory", "ControllerName")',
           data: { departmentName: selectedValue };
           success: function (result) {
               $('#targetElement').html(result); // assign rendered output to target element's ID
           }
       });
   }
});
```

2) Remove `FormCollection` and use a string argument which has same name as AJAX callback argument, also make sure the action method returns `PartialView`:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult EmployeeDeptHistory(string departmentName)    
{
    IEnumerable<EmployeeDepartmentHistory> empHistList;    
    using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))    
    {    
        empHistList = con.Query<EmployeeDepartmentHistory>("sp_StoredProc", new { DeptId = departmentName }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);    
    }

    return PartialView("_EmployeeDeptHistory", empHistList);    
}
```

3) Finally, don't forget to add ID for target element specified by AJAX callback's `success` part to load partial view:

**View**

```
<div id="targetElement">
    @Html.Partial("_EmployeeDeptHistory")
</div>
```

Comment: your response is really helpful. how could i set default value  for default text '-- Select --'. because i don't want ajax request on default text selection.